# Тип подчинительной связи

Tags: синтаксис

Как определить тип подчинительной связи в словосочетании: "Вызвало смех"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Управление, так как зависимое слово отвечает на вопрос винительного падежа.

Answer (score 0):

Это примыкание. Главное слово связывается по смыслу и интонационно.

Answer (score 0):

однозначно управление, так как главное слово вызвать требует определённого падежа. В данном случае винительного